# Opening a Material UI modal from a Material UI AppBar within a Next.js page is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am brand new to React.js and Next.js and am having issues opening a Material UI modal from a Material UI AppBar within a Next.js page.

Most of the code I have here is copied directly from the Material UI website.

I have a page **TopMenu.tsx** that looks like this:

```
import styles from './SearchHeader.module.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import { useAuth } from 'react-oidc-context';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';
import HelpCenterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HelpCenter';
import handleClickOpen from './HelpModal'

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
    const auth = useAuth();

    const user: string = auth?.user?.profile?.unique_name as string;
    const displayUser: boolean = !!user;

    const handleLogout = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        auth.signoutRedirect();
        return true;
    };

    return (
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton disableRipple disableFocusRipple style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }} onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                        <HelpCenterIcon fontSize='large' sx={{ mr: 2 }}></HelpCenterIcon>
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                        {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION_INFO}
                    </Typography>
                    {
                        displayUser && <div className={styles.loginInfo}><span><AccountCircleIcon />{user} ( <a href="#" onClick={handleLogout} className={styles.logout}>Logout</a> )</span></div>
                    }
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

This page, itself, is imported into **index.js** like so:

```
import TopMenu from '../components/TopMenu'
// .
// .
// .
<TopMenu />
```

Here is my **HelpModal.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

function PaperComponent(props) {
    return (
        <Draggable handle="#draggable-dialog-title" cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}>
            <Paper {...props} />
        </Draggable>
    );
}

export default function DraggableDialog() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                Open draggable dialog
            </Button>
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} PaperComponent={PaperComponent} aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title">
                <DialogTitle style={{ cursor: 'move' }} id="draggable-dialog-title">
                    Subscribe
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates occasionally.
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose}> Cancel </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose}>Subscribe</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Whenever I click the `<IconButton><HelpCenterIcon /></IconButton>`, I get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Source
src\components\HelpModal.tsx (20:28) @ React

  18 | 
  19 | export default function DraggableDialog() {
> 20 | const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
     |                        ^
  21 | 
  22 | const handleClickOpen = () => {
  23 |     setOpen(true);
```

Trying to debug this:

1. I do not have mismatching versions of React.
2. I believe this may be the issue, but, as I said, I am brand new to React.js and Next.js and have no idea how to "fix" this.
3. I do have more than one copy of React, as it is imported in both `TopMenu.tsx` and `HelpModal.tsx`. However, I do not know how to remove one without causing further errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is related to how you're importing and using React hooks, like `useState`, can only be used within the body of a function component, not at the top level of a module. When you import `HelpModal` into `TopMenu` and call `handleClickOpen` from there, you're essentially trying to use `useState` in the scope of `TopMenu`, which is not allowed.

#### TopMenu.tsx

```
import styles from './SearchHeader.module.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import { useAuth } from 'react-oidc-context';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';
import HelpCenterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HelpCenter';
import HelpModal from './HelpModal'; // Import the HelpModal component

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
    const auth = useAuth();

    const user: string = auth?.user?.profile?.unique_name as string;
    const displayUser: boolean = !!user;

    const handleLogout = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        auth.signoutRedirect();
        return true;
    };

    // State and function for HelpModal
    const [helpModalOpen, setHelpModalOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const handleHelpModalOpen = () => {
        setHelpModalOpen(true);
    };
    const handleHelpModalClose = () => {
        setHelpModalOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton disableRipple disableFocusRipple style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }} onClick={handleHelpModalOpen}>
                        <HelpCenterIcon fontSize='large' sx={{ mr: 2 }}></HelpCenterIcon>
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                        {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION_INFO}
                    </Typography>
                    {
                        displayUser && <div className={styles.loginInfo}><span><AccountCircleIcon />{user} ( <a href="#" onClick={handleLogout} className={styles.logout}>Logout</a> )</span></div>
                    }
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            {/* Render the HelpModal component */}
            <HelpModal open={helpModalOpen} onClose={handleHelpModalClose} />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

#### HelpModal.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

function PaperComponent(props) {
    return (
        <Draggable handle="#draggable-dialog-title" cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}>
            <Paper {...props} />
        </Draggable>
    );
}

export default function HelpModal({ open, onClose }) { // Accept open and onClose as props
    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={onClose}> {/* Use onClose to close the modal */}
                Open draggable dialog
            </Button>
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose} PaperComponent={PaperComponent} aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title">
                <DialogTitle style={{ cursor: 'move' }} id="draggable-dialog-title">
                    Subscribe
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates occasionally.
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button autoFocus onClick={onClose}> Cancel </Button>
                    <Button onClick={onClose}>Subscribe</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. The whole "hook" thing is really throwing me; I'm just having trouble grasping the concept. I guess I'll be finding things to read on hooks.